# Which app controls Yes/No Authentication in Android?

Tags: android, authentication

Google has recently updated its authentication mechanism and occasionally asks whether you are loging in (Yes / No) rather than request a code.

Does anyone know the app on the phone that is behind the Yes/No action?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google play services** showing the screen while you making the login action.

for more info: http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-prompt-you-can-now-just-tap-yes-or-no-on-ios-android-to-approve-gmail-sign-in/